# visual studio 2008 extended c# intellisense

Tags: .net, xml, visual-studio, intellisense

If I have an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<CATALOG>  
  <TITLE>Title1</TITLE>  
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
</CATALOG>
```

can I call Catalog tag like a class name from intellisense when I edit c# application ? and his child Title1 and USA ?

Example with intellisense VS 2008 c# :

1) System.DateTime.Now;

2) and in my case: 
Catalog
Catalog.Title1
Catalog.USA

and the MOST important thing is:  I don't need to have any assembly references or no implemented classes. 
I must to solve this task only with xml files without dlls or classes.
It's possible? and how?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry but I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about. Can you reword the question somehow? Otherwise this will probably get closed.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something as follows

```
 XDocument catalogueXml
                  = XDocument.Load("books.xml");
   CatalogItem item = (from catalog in
                                    catalogueXml.Descendants("CATALOG")
                      select new CatalogItem
                      {
                        Name = catalog.Element("TITLE").Value,
                        Country = catalog.Element("COUNTRY").Value
                      }).FirstOrDefault();
```

you can still get anonymous object but better to have a defined class

```
 public class CatalogItem
 {  
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public string Country { get; set; }
 }
```

for step by step process and better insight, this is a must have read

- [**Clever: XML to Schema Inference
  Wizard for Visual Studio 2008**](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CleverXMLToSchemaInferenceWizardForVisualStudio2008.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

It's not possible without coding it yourself in a wrapper class. The closest you'll get it linq to xml, but of course, thats an assembly you'd need to register!